# SVG letter R for eyechart

Tags: svg

Folks, let me start by saying that StackOverflow has been invaluable help in my project to design an open-source javascript eye-testing chart. Thank you all.

My question is how best to draw a capital letter R in a 5 high by 4 wide grid, that will work at 0.1 alpha (so no overlapping elements allowed).

Here's my best attempt so far. The difficulty is in the meeting between the arc and the diagonal, which is not a straight line.

```
<svg id="Snellen_R" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"     viewBox="0,0,4,5" height="8.73mm" style="margin: 3.49mm;">
            <path d="M 0.5 5 V 0.5 H 2 M 2 0.5 C 3.5 0.5 3.5 2.5 2 2.5 H 0.5"
            stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="1" >
            </path>
            <polygon points="1.4,3 2.1,3 2.2,2.99 2.3,2.98 2.35,2.97 2.4,2.96 2.45,2.95 2.5,2.94 4,5 2.8,5" fill="black"  />
            </svg>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually no problem having elements overlapping. Just apply the opacity setting to the whole `<svg>` element instead of setting separate fill-opacity and stroke-opacity values for the drawing elements inside it.

```html
<p>
  <svg viewBox="0,0,4,5" height="100" style="margin: 3.49mm;">
    <path d="M 0.5 5 V 0.5 H 2 M 2 0.5 C 3.5 0.5 3.5 2.5 2 2.5 H 0.5" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0.1">
    </path>
    <polygon points="1.32,2.9 2.12,2.9 2.42,2.9 4,5 2.8,5" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.1" />
  </svg>
  <br/>Opacity applied to <tt>&lt;path&gt;</tt> and <tt>&lt;polygon&gt;</tt> elements</p>

<p>
  <svg viewBox="0,0,4,5" height="100" style="margin: 3.49mm; opacity:0.1">
    <path d="M 0.5 5 V 0.5 H 2 M 2 0.5 C 3.5 0.5 3.5 2.5 2 2.5 H 0.5" stroke="black" fill="none" stroke-width="1">
    </path>
    <polygon points="1.32,2.9 2.12,2.9 2.42,2.9 4,5 2.8,5" fill="black" />
  </svg>
  <br/>Opacity applied to <tt>&lt;svg&gt;</tt> element</p>
```

Comment: Yes! that's the answer. Requires me to make a small renovation on my code to separate colour and opacity but it's the perfect solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Inkscape may be able to help you. It's an open source vector graphics editor. I've used it several times for creating text graphics. If anything you can use Inkscape to draw your letter, and then look at the code it generates. You can also save your graphic to a .svg file, or export to another format such as .png. 
Here is the link: 
https://inkscape.org/en/ 
Plenty of youtube tutorials out there as well. Good luck!

Comment: I was just about to type that exact answer when your answer came in!  Great advice and it's exactly what I would do in this situation... export a single letter as SVG, then open it in a text editor and learn what I can from that.